# Unexpected border for CStatic text in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Here is a excerpt of code actually draws the text, the class `MineCStatic` is derived from `CStatic` with a member `m_textColor`set by the client code:

```
    SIZE si;
    if(::GetTextExtentPoint32(pDC->m_hDC, str, (int)str.GetLength(), &si))
    {
        CSize size = si;
        pDC->SetTextColor( m_textColor );
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        DWORD style = GetStyle();
        if(m_bDrawTransparent)
            style &= ~SS_OWNERDRAW;
        if(style & SS_CENTER )
            pDC->TextOut((rect.Width()-size.cx)/2,(rect.Height()-size.cy)/2,str,str.GetLength());
        else if(style & SS_RIGHT)
            pDC->TextOut(rect.Width()-size.cx,(rect.Height()-size.cy)/2,str,str.GetLength());
        else
            pDC->TextOut(0,0,str,str.GetLength());

    }
```

The result goes like (with a default black color):

```
    m_title_font = new CFont;
    createFontResult = 
        m_title_font->CreateFont(64*rate,0,0,0,FW_HEAVY,FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH, "Arial");

        m_text.Create("0%",WS_EX_TRANSPARENT|SS_OWNERDRAW  ,rc,this,IDC_PATCH_CURRENTDATA);
        m_text.SetFont(m_title_font);  // MineCStatic instance
```

[image]

Where comes the green edge color? How can I eliminate it.

Comment: It might be anti-aliasing. Try setting your background color close to the average background, even though you're theoretically not using the background color.

Comment: @MarkRansom Actually it will gone when I set a background image to the control, and I suppose it might work as well by setting a background color.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596961/anti-aliased-text-in-a-transparent-net-form and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533818(v=vs.85).aspx.