# C# - Capture screenshot of window under pointer

Tags: c#, screenshot

I am making a screen capturing application.

There's answer on how to capture an active window, but I want to be able to capture a window under mouse even if it's not active.

Do I understand correctly that I need to find handle of a window under mouse and then call *Image.captureWindow(IntPtr handle)*?

Comment: Prehaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715094/how-do-i-capture-the-current-screen-as-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following function to get the cursor position in context of screen

```
    POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
    //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
}
```

Now you will have to use the EnumWindow function to enumerate all top level windows and then for each try this

```
    if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
{
    //p.x and p.y are now relative to hwnd's client area
}
```

when you get both the values positive for a window, thats the window on which your cursor is. Here is an example of how to capture a window from its handle

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19192/How-to-capture-a-Window-as-an-Image-and-save-it

Hope this helps you

Comment: Stackoverflow didn't allow me to answer my own question, and I figured out how to make it work. I used code from http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/ 
`    var curWindowHndl = WindowFromPoint(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    ScreenCapture cs = new ScreenCapture();
    cs.CaptureWindowToFile(curWindowHndl, "capture.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);`

Do you think your code is cleaner?

Comment: I have tried to explain you same thing but in a different way. Window from point will give you the exact windw (Remember, all buttons, statusbar, toolbar buttons, textboxes etc. all are windows) and I am sure that you don't want to capture them. I assume that you want to capture top level window only.